# Calling an action in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation like when i submit the employee form i need to check for a boolean value in employee_controller if it is set then i need to invoke a create action in AddressController. what is the best way to do it ? Whether i need to create an instance like AddressController .new and call the method ? and there is no relationship between employee and address.

Comment: I think you have to refactor your address creation logic so you can place it on the model; so you don't have to do weird calls between controllers.

Comment: here i just gave an example it's not an real time scenario actually there is no connection between those two models. it's like submit a form and send an email

Comment: show us the (simplified) code to see if you have this real need. Calling actions on different controllers is utterly ill-advised. As @Mauricio says, the usual advice is moving the code to the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to call an action in AddressController when you submit and Employee form?

A better/cleaner idea might be to interact with the Address model from within the Employees_controller. Nothing wrong with that!

Comment: ya gt it .. i did it like that .. sry i haven't updated the post .. thx for ur help